# Send keypress one time but as if the key is pressed down

Tags: windows, keyboard

Is there a way to sendInput/PostMessage/SendMessage as if the key is pressed down without looping, just a simple oneliner which tells the computer that the key is pressed down (while its not) and it acts as if it were?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try sending a `WM_KEYDOWN` without sending a `WM_KEYUP` afterwards?

[WM_KEYDOWN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keydown)

Comment: Yes. PostMessage(hwNd, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_UP, 0); and also tried with Input, it only sends it once

Comment: You can use a tool like spy++ to inspect the window messages of the target process and window. Then you could see what is being used when holding it down yourself (physically - and if it works like this).

Comment: Thanks that was a good idea to check messages, but even if I put flags for repeat, it doesn't actually do that